# Firebase Database - How to know how much Space am I using?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I can't find that information in the console. I thought I could export the JSON and see the actual size of the file but I don't know if there is a better way.

I think it is somehting important to know if you need to upgrade your plan or not.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [connections tab](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/usage/current-billing/connections) in the Firebase console that shows the recent number of connections.

Comment: Hi Frank! Any word on this? I was too wondering how would I keep track of the current number of clients connected to the app at a given time. It’s especially useful for those vertical apps where clients pay ‘by the seat’. It would be great to be able to limit the number of connections via dashboard. Thanks!

Comment: There is a [connections tab](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/usage/current-billing/connections) in the Firebase console that shows the current connections. These is no way to configure a limit on that.