# Tracking Firebase simultaneous connections

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an app which I want to design for Android and iOS but wants to use Firebase's free plan. It allows max 100 simultaneous connections.

I want to check how many simultaneous connections are accessing my real time database. Is there any way to see how many connections are connected at the moment?

Comment: Those statistics are currently not available, but will be added to the Firebase Console in the future. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664592/firebase-database-how-to-know-how-much-space-am-i-using

Comment: I got my answer, Thanks!